# How the property "filter" of CALayer works in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to dig into this subject, but I found really difficult to understand how the `filter` property works.

**From Documentation:**
*Filter properties should be modified by calling setValue:forKeyPath: on each layer that the filter is attached to.*

The `filter` property is an array... so my question is: how can I create the keyPath?!?! 
In OSX we can set a name for any filter and access the filter through a path like this :`"filters.myFilterName.filterPropery"`. 
But in iOS we can't use the `setName` function on a filter! I can't find documentation about this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Also from documentation :** *Note: You cannot add filters to layer objects in iOS.*

Sorry.